# jasckson libraries in google app engine not included in whitelist

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

when I have these imports in my code or use any of the classes and and methods, I get this error from intelli J IDE.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

 Class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' is not included in App Engine JRE White List
```

this does not result in any Maven  build errors but or any errors in production. but why is the IDE flagging the error.
Class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference' is not included in App Engine JRE White List

Answer (score -1):

Those imports aren't part of the Java Application Programming Interface (Java API)
They are library that are created and in order for you to use them, you have to download and add the jar file in your java build path library

Comment: these libraries have been added by using maven, its a google app engine project.